# how to automatically add a foreign key in django model form

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class OtherData(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='other_data')

class ProductImage(models.Model):
  other_data = models.ForeignKey(OtherData, verbose_name='Select title')
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='product_image')
  image = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='images/')
  featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What I wanted is add images to otherdata instance automatically. I tried writing the views.py as follows.

```
def image_create(request, id=None):
  other_data = get_object_or_404(OtherData, id=id)
  form =ImageForm(request.POST or None)
  if form.is_valid():
      instance=form.save(commit=False)
      instance.other_data = other_data
      instance.save()
```

But getting the error  IntegrityError at /image/add/

NOT NULL constraint failed: cars_trucks_productimage.other_data_id

Comment: post your traceback.

Comment: This is the actual error now, (previous mentioned error I got when if clause was there).Page not found (404), No OtherData matches the given query.

Comment: If you are uploading a file in the **ImageForm**, you need to do `form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)` to include the files in the form submitted.

Comment: Still I am getting IntegrityError at /image/add/

NOT NULL constraint failed: cars_trucks_productimage.other_data_id

Comment: Traceback can be seen in this link http://dpaste.com/3ZW6G8K